# Google API-change, results in a MONO error: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler:.ctor (): method body is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I had to change the auth system behind the Google Analytics API following the old auth system becoming defunct. As a result of a SO post, my auth file went from:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        var service = new AnalyticsService("mrfreeman.com");
        service.setUserCredentials("robot@mrfreeman.com", "jellyfish");
        return service;
    });

    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsNewsletterTrackingSource>().As<INewsletterTrackingSource>();
    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsSearchTrackingSource>().As<ISearchTrackingSource>();

    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsEmailLinkTracker>().As<IEmailLinkTracker>();
}
```

To:

```
private const string ServiceAccountEmail = "blabla@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

private static readonly string KeyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Key.p12");

private static readonly X509Certificate2 Certificate = new X509Certificate2(KeyPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
private readonly ServiceAccountCredential _credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics" }
       }.FromCertificate(Certificate));

protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        _credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Wait();
        var service = new AnalyticsService("mrfreeman.com");

        var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("shazbot2.0");
        requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", _credential.Token.AccessToken));
        service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

        return service;
    });

    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsNewsletterTrackingSource>().As<INewsletterTrackingSource>();
    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsSearchTrackingSource>().As<ISearchTrackingSource>();

    builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsEmailLinkTracker>().As<IEmailLinkTracker>();
}
```

Doing all the necessary boiler plate of copying the generated developer email address and P12 key into the project.

The problem is this: It works on Windows but throws problems with the services running on mono and are dependant on the Analytics module. Currently using 4.0.2 version of Mono.

What I've tried:

- Using old and new versions of mono - 3.10 and 4.2.0 pre-release to run the service (which is itself built by Visual Studio) and check if exception is produced.
- Import System.Net.Http and copy to local (currently not referenced in service) - still produces same exception

At this stage I'm cornered into learning the new Google Analytics API and re-writing everything from scratch as I tried to use the old API but update the Auth API with little luck, but feel this a blunt-instrument type solution.

The stack trace is the same on any version and is:

```
FATAL Unhandled exception occurred.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler:.ctor (): method body is empty.

  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x40280100 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x4027ff90 + 0x0002d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential..ctor (Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Initializer initializer) <0x4027f6d0 + 0x00438> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Analytics.AnalyticsModule..ctor () <0x4027ed00 + 0x00103> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x00079> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (Boolean nonPublic) <0x7f82579c1ec0 + 0x00116> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1e70 + 0x00049> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1c10 + 0x0005c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T] () <0x7f82578dfb70 + 0x0008a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (IModuleRegistrar registrar) <0x40273470 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder) <0x40273330 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.BuildContainer (ILog log) <0x402730e0 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.ExecuteJob (System.Type jobType) <0x4021abe0 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0 
Unknown errno: Protocol error


Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler:.ctor (): method body is empty.

  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x40280100 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x4027ff90 + 0x0002d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential..ctor (Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Initializer initializer) <0x4027f6d0 + 0x00438> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Analytics.AnalyticsModule..ctor () <0x4027ed00 + 0x00103> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x00079> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (Boolean nonPublic) <0x7f82579c1ec0 + 0x00116> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1e70 + 0x00049> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1c10 + 0x0005c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T] () <0x7f82578dfb70 + 0x0008a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (IModuleRegistrar registrar) <0x40273470 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder) <0x40273330 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.BuildContainer (ILog log) <0x402730e0 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.ExecuteJob (System.Type jobType) <0x4021abe0 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler:.ctor (): method body is empty.

  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x40280100 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient (Google.Apis.Http.CreateHttpClientArgs args) <0x4027ff90 + 0x0002d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential..ctor (Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Initializer initializer) <0x4027f6d0 + 0x00438> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Analytics.AnalyticsModule..ctor () <0x4027ed00 + 0x00103> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x7f8257b94780 + 0x00079> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (Boolean nonPublic) <0x7f82579c1ec0 + 0x00116> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1e70 + 0x00049> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x7f82579c1c10 + 0x0005c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T] () <0x7f82578dfb70 + 0x0008a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (IModuleRegistrar registrar) <0x40273470 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule[TModule] (Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder) <0x40273330 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.BuildContainer (ILog log) <0x402730e0 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at jellyfish.Cron.Program.ExecuteJob (System.Type jobType) <0x4021abe0 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue, So thought try removing and adding the following DLLS to fix it.

Removed System.net.http, OkHttp, ModernClient. Found the issue was with ModernClientHttp and OkHttp dlls added under references.

I have removed OkHttp and ModernClientHttp and added the ModernClientHttp via Nuget and that works for me.
Give a try if that helps.